# Tile Overlay is not showing in Android Google Maps API onResume

Tags: android, google-maps, android-lifecycle, onresume, wms

I have a custom *WmsTileProvider* in order to display some WMS Tiles in a Google Map using the Android Google Map API.

After starting the app the tiles are visible and rendered at the correct position on the map.

But if I pause my app by going to the main screen and resuming the app my tiles are not showing.

Do I have to execute *clearTileCache* on every *TileOverlay*? Or do I have to remove and add all tiles again to the map?

I add the *TileOverlay* with this code:
I'm adding my TileOverlays with this code in onMapReady:

```
CachedTileProvider tileProviderOverlay = new CachedTileProvider(m_context, index, null);
TileOverlayOptions tileOverlayOptions = new TileOverlayOptions()
                .tileProvider(tileProviderOverlay).zIndex(-1);
TileOverlay tileOverlay = m_googleMap.addTileOverlay(tileOverlayOptions);
        tileOverlay.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: I added some code in the question.